# can we parse the Rss feed containg the link tag which contains image in html format

Tags: android, xml, parsing, rss

I am doing a Mobile Updates  project an Android APP developing which needs to get the daily updates of new launched mobiles in market.

So for this i used the following link :http://techiedreams.com/android-simple-rss-reader/

By using the rss feed  of link: (http://mobiles.sulekha.com/rss/latest-mobile-updates.htm)
 and obtained the feeds from it the title and description  also but could not get the image i am unable to understand how to parse it .

my Dom parser code as modified from the sample code:

```
package com.example.mobileupdates.parser;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class DOMParser {
    private RSSFeed _feed = new RSSFeed();

    public RSSFeed parseXml(String xml) {

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(xml);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            // Create required instances
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
            dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            // Parse the xml
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            // Get all <item> tags.
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            int length = nl.getLength();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Node currentNode = nl.item(i);
                System.out.println(nl.getLength());
                RSSItem _item = new RSSItem();

                NodeList nchild = currentNode.getChildNodes();
                int clength = nchild.getLength();
                System.out.println("length" + clength);
                System.out.println("nodes" + nchild);

                // Get the required elements from each Item
                for (int j = 0; j < clength; j = j + 1) {

                    Node thisNode = nchild.item(j);
                    String theString = null;
                    String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();

                    theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

                    if (theString != null) {
                        if ("title".equals(nodeName)) {
                            // Node name is equals to 'title' so set the Node
                            // value to the Title in the RSSItem.
                            _item.setTitle(theString);
                        }

                        else if ("description".equals(nodeName)) {
                            _item.setDescription(theString);

                            // Parse the html description to get the image url
                            String html = theString;
                            org.jsoup.nodes.Document docHtml = Jsoup
                                    .parse(html);
                            Elements imgEle = docHtml.select("img");
                            _item.setImage(imgEle.attr("src"));
                        }

                        else if ("pubDate".equals(nodeName)) {

                            // We replace the plus and zero's in the date with
                            // empty string
                            String formatedDate = theString.replace(" +0000",
                                    "");
                            _item.setDate(formatedDate);
                        }

                    }
                }

                // add item to the list
                _feed.addItem(_item);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        // Return the final feed once all the Items are added to the RSSFeed
        // Object(_feed).
        return _feed;
    }

}

By changing this block of code  i got title  and description but no image obtained 
// Get the required elements from each Item
                for (int j = 0; j < clength; j = j + 1) {


please help me in obtaining  it  or can we have any other ways to do thi application without rss feeds
```